# Let IsMouseOver="True" Trigger effect stays for a moment even after mouse is left off

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

When I put my mouse on 1st image, 2nd image will appear. When I leave my mouse on 1st image, 2nd image will straight away fade off. How to do to make 2nd image to keep on appear for a few second even after l leave off my mouse on the 1st image?

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="P">
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource showA}"/>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>

<Button Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding Path=PressC}" CommandParameter="cam" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Name="1" Source="/W;component/Images/1.png" Height="100" />
                        <Image Name="2" Source="/W;component/Images/2.png" Height="200" Width="100" Margin="50,-33,-50,0" Visibility="Hidden" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">          
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="imgPressedKeyboard05" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="2" Duration="0:0:.5" BeginTime="0:0:0"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="imgPressedKeyboard05" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="2" To="0" Duration="0:0:.5" BeginTime="0:0:1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>

                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="999"/>                           
                            <Setter TargetName="pressed5" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>                                    
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use animations instead of a simple `Setter`. One in the `EnterActions` to make it visible, one in the `ExitActions` to hide it after a given time. To animate `Visibility` you can use an [`ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.objectanimationusingkeyframes.aspx).